# Output random.sample to Text box

Tags: python, tkinter

Below is my Tkinter GUI, I run the code using linux terminal.
The GUI is outputting the results of `random.sample` to the terminal, but I want it to output the results of `random.sample` to the `output` Text box above the button.
I have tried changing the `def x():` to output instead of print, I have tried changing Text on output to `command=x`, `x`, and `random.sample`.

```
from Tkinter import *
import random
import webbrowser

url = 'http://www.google.co.uk'

# open browser and display url at line 5
def OpenUrl():
    webbrowser.open(url)

# define x
def x():
    print(random.sample(range(1, 60),6))

# Make window
window = Tk()
window.title("UK Lotto Killa")
window.geometry("275x275")

# define title, nym, year
l1 = Label(window, text="    UK Lotto Number Generator", font="bold")
l1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
l2 = Label(window, text="  bitsnpcs (2018)", fg="grey", font="none 8")
l2.grid(row=13, column=1, sticky=W)

# output box
output = Text(window, width=23, height=2)
output.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)

# spacing 
l3 = Label(window, text="     ")
l3.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
l3 = Label(window, text="     ")
l3.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)
l3 = Label(window, text="     ")
l3.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
l3 = Label(window, text="     ")
l3.grid(row=10, column=1, sticky=W)
l3 = Label(window, text="     ")
l3.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W)
l3 = Label(window, text="     ")
l3.grid(row=12, column=1, sticky=W)

# You have options
l3 = Label(window, text="                You have Options - ")
l3.grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=W)
l3 = Label(window, text="   Donate % of winnings to favorite project.")
l3.grid(row=8, column=1, sticky=W)
l3 = Label(window, text="   Donate stake to favorite project.")
l3.grid(row=9, column=1, sticky=W)

# button to generate numbers
Button(window, text="Generate Numbers", width=16, command = x).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)

# open source donation button
Button(window, text="Donate", width=6, command=OpenUrl).grid(row=11, column=1, sticky=W)

# all code goes above here
# finish making window
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I recommend the first thing you do is start over with nothing but a single text widget, and only enough code to make that work. Then, read some documentation about the methods on the text widget, and figure out how to put data into that text widget. It's well documented, and there are examples all over the internet.

Comment: @BryanOakley thank you for advice :)

Comment: @fhdrsdg thankyou for improving with edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your x() function as:-

```
def x():
    sampleList = random.sample(range(1, 60),6)
    print(sampleList)
    sampleRandomNumberListAsString = ','.join(str(x) for x in sampleList)
    output.delete(1.0, END)
    output.insert(END, sampleRandomNumberListAsString)
```

Here output is the reference to the Text() object whose text has to display the list of random numbers. And sampleRandomNumberListAsString is the String representation of the Random Numbers Selected by random()

Comment: you welcome, kindly accept n vote up if you find the solution useful :)